# Placing TikZ drawings in a minipage side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, captions, minipage

I've some problems with aligning some drawings I made with TikZ:
I want these two TikZ pictured below to be displayed side by side with the two captions being on the same horizontal level. Unfortunately, right now the caption of the second drawing appears well below the first caption because the second drawing is a bit larger. How can I add some blank space above the first drawing so that the two captions are vertically aligned?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=20mm,
every node/.style={fill=blue!75,circle, draw, inner sep=2pt},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm,nodes={fill=blue!60}},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=20mm,nodes={fill=blue!45}},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=10mm,nodes={fill=blue!35}}]
\node {5}
      child {node {2}}
      child {node {9}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\captionof{figure}{Caption 1}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=20mm,
every node/.style={fill=blue!75,circle, draw, inner sep=2pt},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm,nodes={fill=blue!60}},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=20mm,nodes={fill=blue!45}},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=10mm,nodes={fill=blue!35}}]
\node {1}
      child {node {5}
         child {node {1}}
         child[missing]
      }
      child {node {8}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\captionof{figure}{Caption 2}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do the real captions have the same number of lines? My compliments for the really good minimal example!

Answer (score 17):

This is exactly what the `\subcaptionbox` command (from the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package) was designed for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=footnotesize}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Caption for first subfigure}[.5\textwidth]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=20mm,
every node/.style={fill=blue!75,circle, draw, inner sep=2pt},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm,nodes={fill=blue!60}},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=20mm,nodes={fill=blue!45}},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=10mm,nodes={fill=blue!35}}]
\node {5}
      child {node {2}}
      child {node {9}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\subcaptionbox{Caption for the seconf figure. This will span several lines for the example; in fact, it will span three lines}[.5\textwidth]{\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=20mm,
every node/.style={fill=blue!75,circle, draw, inner sep=2pt},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm,nodes={fill=blue!60}},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=20mm,nodes={fill=blue!45}},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=10mm,nodes={fill=blue!35}}]
\node {1}
      child {node {5}
         child {node {1}}
         child[missing]
      }
      child {node {8}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

One option is to use `[b]` position specifier to the `minipage`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=20mm,
every node/.style={fill=blue!75,circle, draw, inner sep=2pt},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm,nodes={fill=blue!60}},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=20mm,nodes={fill=blue!45}},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=10mm,nodes={fill=blue!35}}]
\node {5}
      child {node {2}}
      child {node {9}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\captionof{figure}{Caption 1}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=20mm,
every node/.style={fill=blue!75,circle, draw, inner sep=2pt},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm,nodes={fill=blue!60}},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=20mm,nodes={fill=blue!45}},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=10mm,nodes={fill=blue!35}}]
\node {1}
      child {node {5}
         child {node {1}}
         child[missing]
      }
      child {node {8}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\captionof{figure}{Caption 2}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also specify a `height` to the `minipage`s and use `\vfill` after `\end{tikzpicture}` so that both the pictures are aligned at the top line: `\begin{minipage}[b][0.28\textheight]{0.6\textwidth}`

Constraint: If two captions span different number of lines, then first lines are not top aligned.

Using `tabular*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}cc@{}}
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=20mm,
every node/.style={fill=blue!75,circle, draw, inner sep=2pt},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm,nodes={fill=blue!60}},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=20mm,nodes={fill=blue!45}},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=10mm,nodes={fill=blue!35}}]
\node {5}
      child {node {2}}
      child {node {9}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}% 
&
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=20mm,
every node/.style={fill=blue!75,circle, draw, inner sep=2pt},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm,nodes={fill=blue!60}},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=20mm,nodes={fill=blue!45}},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=10mm,nodes={fill=blue!35}}]
\node {1}
      child {node {5}
         child {node {1}}
         child[missing]
      }
      child {node {8}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr0.6\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\captionof{figure}{Caption 1}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr0.4\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\captionof{figure}{Caption 2 is some long caption that may go for a second line}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular*}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use `p{...}` column specifiers and regular `tabular` instead of `tabular*`.

Since you have used `\captionof` macro, I will presume that you won't try to float the pictures and hence attempts using `subcaption` and `subfig` will not be presented.

Comment: I'd avoid the `center` environment inside the `minipage`.