# TikZ-cd Diagrams Side-by-Side

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats, minipage, tikz-cd

I have two diagrams – drawn in TikZ-cd – which I'd like to have side-by-side. However, even though I haven't left a blank line between the code for the two diagrams, they still appear above/below one another.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry} %changes margins
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % fancy maths latters
\usepackage{amsmath} %improves equation environment

\usepackage{tikz-cd} %diagrams

\usepackage{subcaption} %side by side diagrams
\usepackage{caption} %customises captions



\title{Side-by-Side Diagrams MWE}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Here are two diagrams that I would like to have side-by-side:

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
    \mathscr{L}_{1} &  & \mathscr{L}_{2}\\
    & p_{1} \arrow[lu] \arrow[ru] &\\
    & \text{Argument} \arrow[u] &\\
    \end{tikzcd} \caption{Many-one pluralism.}
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
    \mathscr{L}_{1} &  & \mathscr{L}_{2}\\
    p_{1} \arrow[u] &  & p_{2} \arrow[u]\\
    & \text{Argument} \arrow[lu] \arrow[ru] &\\
    \end{tikzcd} \caption{One-many pluralism.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which outputs:

[image]

I've also tried using mini-pages, sub-floats (e.g. [Two diagrams side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42270/two-diagrams-side-by-side)), and the subcaption package (e.g. [Placing TikZ drawings in a minipage side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156096/placing-tikz-drawings-in-a-minipage-side-by-side)) to solve the problem, but in each case I get loads of errors... (Maybe these packages are compatible with TikZ but not  TikZ-cd?) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have it with  `floatrow`, if you enable the replacement of `&` with `\&`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry} %changes margins
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % fancy maths latters
\usepackage{amsmath} %improves equation environment
\usepackage{tikz-cd} %diagrams

\usepackage{subcaption} %side by side diagrams
\usepackage{caption} %customises captions
\usepackage{floatrow}
\title{Side-by-Side Diagrams MWE}
\author{I. Ego}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

Here are two diagrams that I would like to have side-by-side:

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \tikzset{column sep=small, ampersand replacement=\&}
\begin{floatrow}
    \centering
    \ffigbox{\begin{tikzcd}
    \mathscr{L}_{1} \& \& \mathscr{L}_{2}\\
    \& p_{1} \arrow[lu] \arrow[ru] \&\\
    \& \text{Argument} \arrow[u] \&\\
    \end{tikzcd}}{\caption{Many-one pluralism.}}
    \ffigbox{\begin{tikzcd}
    \mathscr{L}_{1}\& \& \mathscr{L}_{2}\\
    p_{1} \arrow[u] \& \& p_{2} \arrow[u]\\
    \& \text{Argument} \arrow[lu] \arrow[ru] \&\\
    \end{tikzcd}}{\caption{One-many pluralism.}}
    \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will use floatrow one day :-) I have not knew this package.